# PopoverView issue

Tags: ipad

i am first time using Popoverview, and i have one issue when i am using popover view.

here is the code which i am using it working fine

```
objManage = [[xyViewController alloc]init];
aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objManage]; 

aPopover.delegate = self;
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(768,1004);
[aPopover setPopoverContentSize:size animated:YES];
CGRect rect = importAddress.frame; //CGRectMake(100.0f, 918, 768,900);
[aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
[objManage release];
```

So i am sucessfully open view controller in popoverview.

i have one button in xyViewController class, Ok suppose i click on button popover view dismiss, How can i dismiss popoverview in another class.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call the method dismissPopoverAnimated:(BOOL)animated on the popover

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009306-CH1-SW9